# roots of polynomials with small coefficients

Tags: numerical-analysis, eigenvalues, numpy, polynomials

I would like to compute the roots of a polynomial with exponentially small coefficients.

$$ \sum_{n=0}^N a_n \frac{z^n}{\sqrt{n!}} \tag{$\ast$}$$

where $a_n$ are Normal random variables with mean $0$ and variance $1$.  For simplicity you can just say $a_n \equiv 1$ always.

When the decay is large the coefficients are getting very small.  $\sqrt{n!} \approx (n/e)^{n/2}$ this is causing underflow on my computer.

---

**Q** Calling `np.roots` on $\ast$ for $N=2000$ results errors because the coefficients are too small?.

**What are some possible ways to handle numbers that are getting small this quickly, or can the power method simplify in some other way in this case?**

---

#### What I Learned

Numpy's [`np.roots`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roots.html) appproximates roots as the eigenvalues of the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of the polynomial.

$$ \left[ \begin{array}{cccl} 
0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & -a_n \\
1 & 0 & \dots &0 & -a_{n-1} \\
0 & 1 &  \dots & 0  & -a_{n-2} \\
0 & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & -a_0
\end{array}\right]$$

In term, these eigenvalues are computed using something called [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/).

Without referring to a library, I could maybe implement the [power method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration) on my own.  From initial random vector $b_0 \in S^N$, multiply by $A$ and rescale.

$$ b_{k+1} = \frac{A b_k}{|| A b_k ||}$$

The coefficients are getting small very quickly but the ratio of neighbor coefficients is not growing too fast $b_n = a_n/\sqrt{n!}$

$$ b_n/b_{n+1} = \sqrt{n+1} $$

---

#### Really Simple Example

What are the roots of $\epsilon x^2 + ax + b = 0$ ?  The quadratic formula returns two numbers approximately

$$ x = \frac{ -a + \sqrt{a^2 - 4b \epsilon} }{2\epsilon }
=  \frac{ -a + a\sqrt{1 - 4(b/a) \epsilon} }{2\epsilon }
\approx  -\frac{a}{\epsilon} , -\frac{b}{a}$$

The ratio of the coefficients seems to matter a lot.  In our case, they are of the same order of magnitude $\frac{a}{\epsilon} , \frac{b}{a} \approx \sqrt{n}$

---

Here is some code I wrote incorporating the rescaling suggestion... not many lines.  Certainly it's enough to get the roots, but not sure if I trust it for finer statistics.  Convergence is king here, I think.

```
N = 2000
a = 0.5*(np.random.normal(0,1,N) + 1j*np.random.normal(0,1,N))

fact = np.cumproduct(np.sqrt(np.arange(N)+1)/np.sqrt(N/np.exp(1)))

w = np.roots(a/fact[::-1])
plt.plot(w.real, w.imag, '.')
```

[image]

---

#### Final Version

The obvious (in hindsight) rescaling leads to much more accurate and convincing pictures, that I believe will hold up to further scrutiny.

```
N = 2000
a = 0.5*(np.random.normal(0,1,N) + 1j*np.random.normal(0,1,N))

A = 1j*np.zeros((N,N))
A[:,-1] = a

x = np.arange(N-1)
A[x+1, x] =np.sqrt(x+1)

w = np.linalg.eigvals(A)
plt.plot(w.real, w.imag, '.')
```

[image]

Comment: Did you mean to say "*roots* of a polynomial with exponentially small coefficients" in the first sentence?

Comment: $\sqrt{N!}$ is not representable in double precision arithmetic for $N=2000$ (Sterling's formula indicates that it is roughly equal to $(2000/e)^{1000}\approx 736^{1000}>10^{2800}$). But even if it were, any kind of floating point arithmetic would suffer from catastrophic loss of accuracy because you are evaluating and adding numbers that are on vastly different scales.

Comment: Have you tried the rescaling trick I suggested in a comment to your [other question](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/16404/roots-of-polynomials-of-high-degree-linalgerror-eigenvalues-did-not-converge#comment27492_16404)? That could help.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni The scaling constants are super-exponentially decreasing, so why would that solve the problem?

Comment: @Kirill I am not hoping to eliminate completely the superexponential growth problem, just to mitigate it enough for the numerical methods to converge.

Comment: Another remark: your observation that "[t]he ratio of the coefficients seems to matter a lot" seems related to the Newton polygon, a technique based on these ratios to estimate the magnitude of the roots of a polynomial. See for instance Chapter 3 of Leonardo Robol's thesis http://poisson.phc.unipi.it/compiled-pdf/robol-thesis.pdf.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni The polynomials here have been studied a lot (Gaussian analytic functions, e.g. http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0410343), and have a known limiting distribution of roots, uniform on the disk of radius $\sqrt{N}$ in $\mathbb{C}$. I assume the question only arose because the author tried to verify analytic results by numerical simulation and np.roots failed.

Comment: @Kirill Kabluchko and Zaporozhets [arxiv:1205.5355](http://arxiv.org/abs/1205.5355) finds similar results for other random polynomials ($a_n$ is not normal, just $\mathbb{E}[a_n] = 0$ and $\mathbb{E}[a_n^2]=1$.).  They plot the result for $N = 2000$, which is what I am trying to reproduce.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I can try $\sqrt{k!} \approx (k/e)^{k/2}$ so that $z^k/\sqrt{k!} \approx (ze/k)^{k/2}$ where $k \leq N$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that, if $D$ is invertible, the eigenvalues of $A$ and $DAD^{-1}$ are the same.

You can avoid floating-point underflow when forming the matrix by scaling the companion matrix by a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $D_{ii} = 1/\sqrt{(n-i)!}$.  For the polynomial $x^4 + a x^3/\sqrt{1!} + b x^2/\sqrt{2!} + c x/\sqrt{3!} + d/\sqrt{4!}$, this gives a modified companion matrix of

$$
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
  & & & -d\\
  1/\sqrt{4} & & & -c\\
  & 1/\sqrt{3} & & -b\\
  & & 1/\sqrt{2} & -a\\
\end{array}\right).
$$

You can use a trick such as $p(x) \to x^n p(1/x)$ that inverts the roots of $p$ with respect to the circle in order to get $p$ into the form given above.

I do not know whether LAPACK reliably finds the eigenvalues of such matrices, but all of the entries here are quite reasonably scaled.

Comment: Of course, for a companion matrix built from coefficients with widely varying magnitudes, a preliminary balancing is necessary. An alternative is to instead build a matrix pencil (thus avoiding the need to build a monic polynomial) and use the QZ algorithm with balancing.